# Get redirect url after ajax GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am saving a form using jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: /admin/department/save,
     data: $(".formstyles").serialize(),
     success: function(data, status,xhr) {
       $(contentHolder).html(data);
}});
```

When this url get a hit it saves the form and redirects to `/admin/department/edit/1090`

Here, the ajax get is processed and response is received.

I want redirected url from request headers, somehow.

Answer (score 2):

after success you can redirect url 
window.location.href = URL;

Comment: No, actually initially the request is going to a controller, url:/admin/department/save then the controller redirects the location to /admin/department/edit/1090, the response is coming from this url by means of ajax GET request, i am not getting this url in response headers. I want this url.